# Quick sort algorithm using pointers?

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, quicksort

Trying to create a quick sort algorithm using pointers and am not having much luck. My code compiles but does not work and I'm stumped at how to rectify the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int* partition(int* start, int* stop) {
    int* pivot = stop - 1; // you can randomly pick one as the pivot
    int* i = start;
    int* j = stop - 1;
    for (;;) {
        while (i < pivot && i < stop) ++i; // skip "low" on left side
        while (j >= pivot && j > start) --j; // skip "high" on right side
        if (*i >= *j) break;
        swap(i, j); // swap out-of-place items
    }
    swap(*(stop - 1), *i); // swap pivot to the final place i
    return i;
}


void quickSort(int* start, int* stop) {
    if (stop - start <= 1) return;
    int* pivot = partition(start, stop);
    quickSort(start, pivot);
    quickSort(pivot + 1, stop);
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What did you expect and what did you get instead? Describe the issue to solve, please.

Comment: The program is meant to output the type of algorithm, the size of the dataset and the type of dataset. It currently works for other sort functions but this one returns nothing.

Comment: `int* pivot = stop - 1;`Where is defined stop? How can you be sure that `stop - 1` is an usable address, ie that all your sorted values are stored contiguously?

Comment: In `swap(i, j);` you apparently pass pointers to a function whilst in `swap(*(stop - 1), *i);` you pass `int` values. Which one you think is correct...?

Comment: [I thought this code looked familiar...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102903/quicksort-no-matching-function-for-call-to-c)

Comment: Horrible code, btw. Avoid pointers when not needed (especially when std::vector does the job far better), don't break loops (and therefore don't use loops with true as condition) and I'd also advise you to use brackets even when only one command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be comparing contents of the address instead of the address?
Specifically,

```
while(*i < *pivot)
```

and

```
while(*j >= *pivot)
```

Also you should swap the contents and not the pointers.

```
swap(*i, *j);
```

It is unclear from the question what you want to achieve though. My answer has an underlying assumption that elements of the array you want to sort are stored contiguously.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions `i < pivot` and `j >= pivot` compare *pointers* while you should compare *values pointed* here.